# ParserError: Expected identifier but got reserved keyword 'immutable'

Tags: remix

I am trying to compile a contract with distribition rewards via Remix, but get this error.

```
contracts/contract.sol ParserError: Expected identifier but got reserved keyword 'immutable'
  address public immutable BTC = address(0x7130d2A12B9BCbFAe4f2634d864A1Ee1Ce3Ead9c);
                 ^-------^
```

The code in question:

```
contract DividendPayingToken is ERC20, Ownable, DividendPayingTokenInterface, DividendPayingTokenOptionalInterface {
  using SafeMath for uint256;
  using SafeMathUint for uint256;
  using SafeMathInt for int256;

  address public immutable BTC = address(0x7130d2A12B9BCbFAe4f2634d864A1Ee1Ce3Ead9c);
```

Comment: If it does not change then changed it to constant

Comment: I mean if the variable dose not change, then change “immutable” to constant